# What does it mean using number behind select?

Tags: mysql, select, exists

There are two tables:

```
create table author (id int primary key auto_increment, name varchar(255));
insert into author (name) values ('tingwei');
insert into author (name) values ('jiahui');
insert into author (name) values ('naidan');
insert into author (name) values ('weizhi');
insert into author (name) values ('siyao');

create table book (author_id int primary key auto_increment, book varchar(255));
insert into book (book) values ('I love you');
insert into book (book) values ('I hate you');
insert into book (book) values ('I miss you');
```

But I don't know what does this statement mean by using number 1 behind "select":

```
select *
from author
where exists (select 1 from book where book.author_id = author.id)
```

I've already searched some information online but I got nothing.

Comment: 1 is  a dummy column  .. just for sintax and let the query work  ..  if the where clause in inner subquery  is satisfied  then the row exist and the where condition outside  is solved

Comment: Any value will do, not just `1`. You could use `0`, `-1`, `'a'`, or `'My Little Pony'`. Doesn't matter. Even a non value such `null` will also work.

Comment: EXISTS checks the fact that the record exists. So any synthactically correct columnset may be selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SELECT 1` does just that: it selects the value `1`. When used with `WHERE EXISTS` it does not matter what data the subquery returns, as long as it returns any data (in other words: returns at least one row).